# MySQL performance on JOIN when foreign key is null

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let assume I have a table with some foreign keys to other tables:

```
Person: {
    cityId: ref to Cities table (nullable)
    carId: ref to Cars table (nullable)
}
```

And I have a row with `cityId: 3`, `carId: null`.

If I query and JOIN Cities by cityId and also by Cars by carId, even though carId is null (which is redundant join in this case) - does mysql have an optimization for such redundant join? or better to remove this redundant join query?

Comment: join ignores usually NULL

Comment: Yes, MySQL has such an optimization (like any other relational database) - it will not perform redundant JOINs.

Comment: Please provide SQL and SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you are performing outer joins, not inner joins.

Any inner join with a null won't succeed and the current `Person` won't be selected in the results.

If you perform an outer join by `carId` then the engine will notice immediately and won't bring any related row from the `Cars` table. The query will return the row from `Person` but the columns related to `Card` will be null. In terms of performance, the engine won't do any extra work and the query will be quite performant.